# CSS Chrome Bug? Shows horizontal scroll bar @ 100% table cell

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-tables

I'm just doing my first steps with HTML & CSS, but I wonder why just Chrome shows a horizontal scroll bar for my following code while it shouldn't. Please notice that the bar is just shown at specific zoom levels. I wonder if this is a (known) bug or am I doing something wrong? My current Chrome version is 26.0.1410.64. Here's my MWE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        /* -------------- Setting Default values -------------- */
html, body, div, form, fieldset, legend, label {
   margin: 0;
}

/*
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    body{
        margin-right: 0.05px;
    }
}
*/

nav.main_nav {
    display:table-cell;
}

 div.content {
    padding-left: 5px;  /* <-- important */
    display:table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
        </style>
    </head> 

  <body>
        <nav class="main_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the .content div 100% wide plus 5px. It's that extra 5px that's causing the scrollbar.

Comment: so why isn't the hbar shown consistently in all zoom levels and not at all in FF or IE? How would you let the content cell fill the whole hspace if you use a background color for example?

Comment: yes, that was the reason why I commented the extra 5px as important in my example ...

Comment: this doesn't explain why `margin-right: 0.05px` fixes this for me on all zoom levels